# division from the result sets python function generates 'zero' values

Tags: python, nltk

Goal: I am trying to create an average number of words per sentence.

Steps: use the following two functions.

Results: If I print either of the results from the functions just fine. But when I use division ('/') in the for loop (at the bottom of the code, I get a list of zeros.

Expected: Any advice is appreciated.

```
import nltk.data
from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer

        def wordsInSentences():
            tokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\w+')
            data=[]
            with open ('~/20110622.html', 'r') as f:
                for i in [len(tokenizer.tokenize(i)) for i in f]:
                    data.append(i)
            return data

        def totalSentenceCounter():
            sentence_detector = nltk.data.load('/~/punkt/english.pickle')
            with open ('/~/20110622.html', 'r') as f:
                y= len (['\n'.join(sentence_detector.tokenize (i.strip())) for i in f])
            return y

for i in wordsInSenteces():
print i/int(totalSentenceCounter())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace it with `print float(i)/totalSentenceCounter()`. You are performing integer division as both numerator and denominator are `int`, you need at least one of them to be `float`.

```
>>> print 1/2
0
>>> print float(1)/2
0.5
```

Comment: Glad I could helped.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2, which is what you are using, replace

```
print i/int(totalSentenceCounter())
```

with

```
print i/float(totalSentenceCounter())
```

In Python 3 your existing code will work as expected without any modifications.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.x, integer divisions returns an integers by default.

```
 $ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1 / 5
0
>>> 1 / 2
0
>>> 2 / 3
0
>>> int(0.2)
0
>>> int(0.5)
0
>>> int(0.666)
0
```

In Python 3.x, divisions are more "natural" (i.e. returns a real number) and it returns a float by default, even when the output can be an integer:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 17 2016, 17:05:23) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1 / 5
0.2
>>> 10 / 5
2.0
```

To emulate Python 3 division behavior in Python 2.x, add the `__future__` import at the top of your script, e.g.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from __future__ import division
>>> 1 / 5
0.2
```

Or as the other answers suggested, you could cast either the denominator or numerator into a float before the division operation, e.g.

```
$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 1 / 5
0
>>> 1.0 / 5
0.2
>>> 1 / 5.0
0.2
>>> float(1) / 5
0.2
>>> 1 / float(5)
0.2
```